# Upgraded PHP. Console shows 5.3 but phpinfo still says 5.1.2

Tags: php, linux, lighttpd

I have a need for anonymous functions in php (soundcloud php wrapper) and so I upgraded my audio server to PHP 5.3.   The server is linux CentOS 5.5.

After what I assumed was a successful install, php -v and php-cgi -v both show 5.3 is installed, but the server is still reporting 5.1.2.

I am using lighttpd, not apache.   I can only find one php.ini file on the server.  I've searched through my lighttpd.conf files and cannot for the life of me figure out how to get Lighttpd to see the new PHP version.

Cheers

Edit:  I forgot to mention that I'm using FastCGI.   Here is the fastcgi.conf file for lighttpd:

```
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ((
"bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
"socket" => "/tmp/php.socket",
"max-procs" => 2,
"bin-environment" => (
"PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "16",
"PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
),
"bin-copy-environment" => (
"PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
),
"broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
)))
```

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: Is it possible that the phpinfo page is cached on the server and/or your browser?

Comment: Update your configuration for lighttpd to use 5.3. If you haven't changed it, it will still be using 5.1.2

Comment: @BrianWarshaw How do I do this?  I've looked at my Lighttpd config and it doesnt reference a specific version of php anywhere.  The only reference to PHP is in fastcgi.conf where it lists the bin-path as "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi".   Ive searched the server for any other instances of php-cgi and none exist.

Comment: You can troubleshoot this by:
1. Run `/usr/bin/php-cgi -v`; is the version 5.3? If yes, then you need to restart the server (as well as possibly fast-cgi, which is separate to your server) or change the configuration somewhere
2. If not, there might be a separate package for php-cgi. For example, in Ubuntu there are both php5-cli and php5-cgi packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you restart lighttpd or apache service, the php-cgi processes can still be running.

In order to fix this issue, I stopped the service, then killed php-cgi processes

## killall php-cgi

Then started lighttpd and phpinfo is now showing that im running the new version of PHP.

Many thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on Digital Ocean. I was running PHP 7.2 and upgraded to 7.4.

`php -v` on the command line showed 7.4.5 as expected, but `phpinfo()` showed 7.2.1.

To solve this, I ran:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now `phpinfo()` is showing the correct version.